# adding an instance to migrations model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add an instance of a restaurant to my favorites model but I am getting an error saying "bin/run.rb:441:in `add_favorite_restaurant': undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". In the migrations table the model for favorites consists of the restaurant.id and customer.id, so I'm not understanding why there is an error when the id is used since it is needed...

```
def add_favorite_restaurant(customer)
  puts "What restaurant would you like to add to your favorites?"
  favorite_name = gets.chomp
  restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(name: favorite_name)
  # binding.pry
  Favorite.create(
    restaurant_id: restaurant.id,
    customer_id:   $customer.id
  )
  puts "You have successfully added #{favorite_name} to your favorites"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables that start with a `$` in Ruby are global variables...which should almost never be used.

So, it is pretty clear that the error `undefined method id for nil:NilClass` is coming from this line...

```
customer_id: $customer.id
```

`customer` is a parameter of the `add_favorite_restaurant` method...so you can simply remove the dollar sign to resolve the issue (assuming the argument you pass in is not `nil` and is an instance of `Customer`)...

```
customer_id: customer.id
```

Comment: I tried that before but it still didn't work, so I decided to leave it @Mark Merritt

Comment: By "it still didn't work", do you get the same error message, or a different one?

Comment: Then either `customer` or `restaurant` are `nil`. It looks like you already tried debugging with `binding.pry`. Check the value of customer and restaurant to determine which one is nil...also remove the $ from customer

Answer (score 0):

`customer` is passed as parameter but you use `$customer` - and in the code, the restaurant variable can be nil from the command `restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(name: favorite_name)` once that restaurant not exist in your database